# Does android SDK provide any default methods to add blur like iOS

Tags: android, android-layout, blur, blurry

User opens Home Activity, he taps on `Login Button`, and another activity launches.

Now in Login activity i don't want to use any background color, i want to add blur effect over Home Activity like following.

*This is an iOS screen.*

[image]

I know that there are some third party libraries available that provide this kind of effect but does android SDK provides this type of effect, as iOS provides blur effect in its SDK.

Answer (score 6):

Simple answer, **no**. It is not a native method or even functionality. But you could use some of the alternative supported libraries, like:

[Blurry](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry)

[Android StackBlur](https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur)

[BlurView](https://github.com/Dimezis/BlurView)

[Blurkit](https://github.com/wonderkiln/blurkit-android)

[RealtimeBlurView](https://github.com/mmin18/RealtimeBlurView)

[500px-android-blur](https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur)

Comment: I tried all - and none of them works. Each one either crashes or does nothing (apparently there are some problems with renderscript and androidx). Also, none is updated in last year, so most probably androidX is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**NO --- ANDROID SDK Doesn't provide such functionality**

Unfortunately, android has no straight way with to do a blur view activity; where previous activity's view is blurred..

Above mentioned libs, works mostly to provide a captured image with blur effect and set that to a view's background.

Comment: Maybe in 2020, we have some option except 3d party libs to blur view or layout? No?

Comment: @PonomarenkoOleh what about 2021?

Comment: @SaeedArianmanesh In 2021 year, Android introduced some API for blurring, but I didn't touch this yet. You can read more here: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/window-blurs

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android 12 there is blur window functionality

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/window-blurs